# If 'new' is used to instantiate an object with a factory function does it change anything?

Tags: javascript, object

In the test code below I use a factory function to instantiate a new object in the traditional way without the `new` keyword.  It works as expected.

```js
function testThis(x) {
   let middleStep = {
        firstNumber: x.firstNumber,
        secondNumber: x.secondNumber
    }
    return middleStep;
}

let newObject = testThis({firstNumber: 'ONE', secondNumber: 'TWO'});
// new keyword not used

console.log(newObject.firstNumber);
```

In the next example I use the same method but include the `new` keyword.  It produces the same output and on the surface it seems to work the same way.  Does the `new` keyword change anything when used in this context or is the result the same?

```js
function testThis(x) {
   let middleStep = {
        firstNumber: x.firstNumber,
        secondNumber: x.secondNumber
    }
    return middleStep;
}

let newObject = new testThis({firstNumber: 'ONE', secondNumber: 'TWO'});
// new keyword included

console.log(newObject.firstNumber);
```

Comment: new is for classes, *'just because'* does not mean you should be using it with a function.

Comment: Until today I didn't realize I could put `new` in front of a factory function.  I'm just wondering if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function returns an object, calling it with `new` will be redundant and equivalent to calling it without `new`. From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

> When the code `new Foo(...)` is executed, the following things happen:
>
> 1. A new object is created, inheriting from `Foo.prototype`.
> 2. The constructor function `Foo` is called with the specified arguments, and with this bound to the newly created object. new Foo is equivalent to `new Foo()`, i.e. if no argument list is specified, Foo is called without arguments.
> 3. The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole new expression. **If the constructor function doesn't explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used instead.** (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation process.)

Answer (score 1):

'new' will create a function object. When you just call a function, 'this' will be referred to the window. But if its a 'new' object, then the 'this' referred to the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

I am giving some general information about the usage of "new" with "functions" in java script.
1. "new" can be used for functions as well. It will be considered as function constructor. When we do this way, as a general coding practice, we name the function with first character being upper case

2. When JS engine sees a "new" operator(yes "new" is an operator and has precedence"), it creates an empty object in memory and the engine will assign "this" reference to this newly created empty object.
   At the end of the function constructor, JS engine will populate the empty object with the properties that we create inside constructor function and automatically return the object.
   example:

   //This is a function constructor which accepts two parameters
   function Human(firstname, lastname) {
       this.firstname = firstname;  // "this" will point to humanIdentity
       this.lastname = lastname;
       // JS engine will automatically return the object with above properties
   }

   var humanIdentity = new Human('Mr.', 'JS');